# makeEwsRequestAsync not working in outlook desktop client

Tags: outlook, exchangewebservices, office-addins, office365-apps, outlook-web-app

I'm doing a mail box search in outlook add on using makeEwsRequestAsync request.

```
var mailbox = Office.context.mailbox;
mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(request, callback);
```

It is working good in outlook web client but I always get empty result in outlook desktop client.

call back function:

```
function callback(asyncResult) {

        var result = asyncResult.value;
        var context = asyncResult.context;

        if (asyncResult.status == "succeeded") {

            var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(result.toString());
}
}
```

After xml parsing, $(xmlDoc).text() gives the xml text.

But $(xmlDoc).find('node') is not working in outlook desktop client (Outlook 2013). I tried giving the node name in capitals, lower (eg. s:Envelope, s:envelope, S:ENVELOPE) but find() is not working

What should I do to get the result in outlook desktop client. I'm using outlook 2013.

Comment: You need to give more information (eg what happens it doesn't show or activate or doesn't work) and code, most probably its because you are failing to parse the results correctly (try just returning the unparsed results) which can happen even just with different web browsers (eg does you code work both in chrome and IE?). Mailbox version 1.3 also doesn't work in Outlook 2013 you need Outlook 2016 but you haven't posted enough information to tell if your using that or not.

Comment: @glen thanks, updated my question.

Comment: i'm using windows 10 and is working perfectly in EDGE (IE latest). but $(xml).find('node') is not working in outlook desktop version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the XML differently depending on the client there's a discussion in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp160952.aspx on it. If you dump the contents of result.toString() you will be able to tell what is actually being returned to the Javascript processor running in Outlook and you should then be able to work out how process it correctly.

There are number of examples Microsoft have posted on GitHub eg https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-JavaScript-MakeEWSRequest

Personally I use the following which works across most browsers and desktop outlook version but I generally work by outputting the results first to see what is being returned and then its easy to work out what you should be doing next and which js objects are best to use

```html
function callbackFindItems(asyncResult) {
    //$('#ChkTest').text(asyncResult.value);
    var result = asyncResult.value;
    var context = asyncResult.context;
    var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
    if (is_chrome) {
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var doc = parser.parseFromString(asyncResult.value, "text/xml");
        var values = doc.childNodes[0].getElementsByTagName("ItemId");
        var itemId = values[0].attributes['Id'].value;
        var changeKey = values[0].attributes['ChangeKey'].value;
        var request = UpdateVerb(itemId, changeKey, hexToBase64(_VerOptions));
        var envelope = getSoapEnvelope(request);
       // $('#ChkTest').text(request);
        Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(envelope, updateCallBack);
    }
    else {
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var doc = parser.parseFromString(asyncResult.value, "text/xml");
        var values = doc.childNodes[0].getElementsByTagName("t:ItemId");
        var itemId = values[0].attributes['Id'].value;
        var changeKey = values[0].attributes['ChangeKey'].value;
        var request = UpdateVerb(itemId, changeKey, hexToBase64(_VerOptions));
        var envelope = getSoapEnvelope(request);
        //$('#ChkTest').text(request);
        Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(envelope, updateCallBack);
    }
}
```

Comment: exactly what i did yesterday to solve the issue. thanks :)